# Sitecore: Get parent rendering parameters

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

Consider this scenario in Sitecore MVC: I have a rendering called Rendering A which is a DIV with a placeholder inside (placeholder-a). Then I have a second rendering, named Rendering B, which I place inside of placeholder-a.

Is there a way that my code for Rendering B can read the rendering parameters of Rendering A?

Comment: I don't think your getting a parent rendering here. You are looking at sibling renderings, in this case the one that comes before. Look at @Varun Nehra solution. You could possibly Get the list of renderings and find the one that matches current and do a -1. Of course this presumes that your rendering order will never change, there is probably a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Anton mentioned you cannot get the parent rendering but you can however get a list of all renderings on the current page as follows:

```csharp
var pageContext = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.CurrentOrNull;
if(pageContent!=null)
    var renderings = pageContext.PageDefinition.Renderings;
```

Once you have the renderings you can look up the placeholder values, parameters etc.
Another possibility, not sure if this works for you, is that from the current rendering context you can always get the children renderings. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box it is impossible due to calling of *RenderRendering* pipeline separately for each rendering in placeholder.

I did it by [overriding placeholder control](https://github.com/Antonytm/Sitecore.Mvc.Extension) and allowing to pass additional parameters via placeholder.

e.g.

```
@Html.SitecoreExtended().Placeholder("extendedForRendering", new {ExampleRouteValue1 = "Sitecore MVC Placeholder with rendering view"})
```

In this case I was able to transfer required parameters via placeholders from parent view to child view.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as Rendering A code is executed first, could you possibly add the rendering parameters in the session / cache? and then access it in Rendering B?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a too old question, but I have the same issue. If you use dynamic placeholder, sitecore add to the placeholders name Guid, something like this "`placeholder-name_{GUID}_number-of-item-in-this-placeholder`". So, UniqueId of rendering where you have your `Placeholder-A` is that Guid that sitecore use for your dynamic placeholder

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ASj0.png)